# Inconsistency on border radius on images across browsers and systems?

Tags: image, css

I've spotted some weird behavior across browsers border-radius implementation. Take this code: http://jsfiddle.net/pm7FZ/1/ On Windows every browser excerpt Chrome rounds inner image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuDy.jpg Chrome doesn't and the image stays square.

I don't have OS X, but my friend send me this: https://img.skitch.com/20120925-eypjk593tdest3ud9hcji1sauf.png Seems it behaves differently. Although another friend says that if you set  border-radius to 20px on OS X it will round the image corners on OS X's version of Firefox.

Question - what is happening here? Why so much inconsistency.

It's obviously easy to "fix", just curiosity.

Comment: It's basically the same question why one browser supports a feature while the other one doesn't...

Comment: Different implementation and no implementation are two separate things.

Comment: Nah, not really. In both cases you can't rely on the feature what the mainpoint in professional environment is.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate but here's what I suspect is going on. If you check out the W3C spec for the basic box model (http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-box-20070809/) you'll see a graphic that demonstrates how elements are laid out. Each element has a content area, padding, border, and margin areas. I believe browsers render each of these areas as a layer and where FF would render the 'border layer' on top of the content layer Chrome would render the 'content layer' on top of all the other layers. In your sample if you would remove the height and width attributes from your `img` tag you'll see the image does get rounded but is not affected by the border itself. I haven't found any specification on the way browsers should handle this but I'm pretty sure the Chrome devs chose this method to squeeze out some more performance.